# Jupiter listing delay

Tags: python, swap, liquiditypool, sdk, jupiter

I am working on a bot to swap on Jupiter using python. A lot of the tokens I will be swapping will be newer tokens, (within a few minutes of listing and with a few thousand mktcap). However, when I attempt to swap a newer token with python and the Jupiter sdk, I get a message that the pool is not found. Is this a problem with Jupiter not having the listing yet, and is there a way around this?

I would prefer to use Jupiter over raydium for swaps as it supports limit orders easily

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question?? Pools not found and very slow transaction are making the Jupiter API look suboptimal and not very inviting.

Comment: @RichardOre I didn't get an answer but according to the jupiter docs you just have to wait until it's listed and there's no way around it. https://station.jup.ag/docs/get-your-token-onto-jup